# ES6 module returning empty object

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-module-loader

Gruntfile.js

```
browserify:{
    dist:{
        options:{
            transform:[
                ["babelify"]
            ]
        },
        files:{
            "destination":"source"
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample file written in ES6

```
var HomeController={
  initHomeController: function(appModule){
       console.log("Method Executing:HomeController.initHomeController");
       appModule.controller('HomeController',['$scope',function($scope){

       }]);

  }
};
export default HomeController
```

On transpiling the above file it reduces to

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var HomeController = {
  initHomeController: function initHomeController(appModule) {
    console.log("Method Executing:HomeController.initHomeController");
    appModule.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}]);
  }
};
//var x = HomeController.initHomeController;
//console.log(x);
exports.default = HomeController;

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

Now I am trying to import HomeController in my main file but the HomeController is returning an empty object.
I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake.

```
import HomeController from './es5/controllers/HomeController.js';
  console.log("------",HomeController);
  HomeController.initHomeController(appModule); //initController is method I want to use.
```

Comment: have you tried `import HomeController from './es5/controllers/HomeController.js'.default`?

Comment: @The i tried but grunt task is failing

Comment: What's that `/es5/` doing in the path, shouldn't you import the ES6 module?

Comment: _"This is a sample file written in ES6"_ `initHomeController: function(appModule){` - That's more like ES 5